# "Standard" R benchmarking code?

Tags: r, benchmarking

I am recompiling/upgrading my `R` install and I want to measure performance pre/post upgrade. Is there possibly a standard script to run to time some commonly used functions and libraries? I have already installed `rbenchmark`, but I am just not enough of an `R` user to know what type of code to write to properly benchmark the new installation.

Comment: What kind of performance would you like to measure?

Comment: I guess just all around CPU efficiency. If a given R script can complete in 23.2 seconds and then I recompile the R installation and it can run in 18.5 seconds, then that is a definite boost. I would also, theoretically, like to know which routines/functions get the best speed up. So maybe reading a file doesn't speed up, but matrix dot products get 20% speed up, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen people use [R-benchmark-25](http://r.research.att.com/benchmarks/) as on overall test of R.

When I compile BLAS's, I use something like [what I post here](http://www.avrahamadler.com/2014/04/20/r-3-1-0-openblas-speed-comparisons/) to benchmark matrix operations from various packages.